# How to get the latest data from a Dataframe containing duplicate rows with Primary Keys?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have two Tables.

1. `_Insert`[Main Table]
2. `_Edit`[Contains Updates of Insert table. It can have multiple entries of updates for one Primary Key]

`Primary Key- Loan ID, Month`

_Insert-

```
| Loan ID | Loan Details | Month     |
| 123     | Car Loan     | 01-May-22 |
| 124     | House Loan   | 31-Apr-22 |
```

_Edit-

```
|Loan ID| Loan Details| Month    |
| 123   | Student Loan| 02-May-22|
| 123   | House Loan  | 05-May-22|
```

Now, I've tried to use `dropDuplicates` with the Dataframe which is a merged delta_table of [`Insert+Edit`]

```
df_Insert = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM insertedit""")
df_Insert_filter = df_Insert.dropDuplicates(['Loan_ID', 'Month'])
```

Looks like this doesn't do the required Job. Also while **Loading to SQL from Deltalake** it shows **Error: PrimaryKey Violation, Cannot insert duplicate key in object `dbo.table`**.

What can I do in this case.

Comment: The question needs some additional information. How are you merging the dataframes? How are you loading the delta lake? How are you loading sql db (plain insert? truncate insert? merge?..)

Comment: You need to provide info on how you do the merge - which rows do you want to keep, based on what.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is bit unclear but you can use below code if you want to remove duplicates based on loan id and month columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
win_func = W.partitionBy('loanid').orderBy(desc('month'))
df1 = df.withColumn('rownum',row_number().over(win_func)).filter(col('rownum')==1).drop('rownum')
```